# How to exit from recursive call?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have following code for recursive call.

```
public string success() 
{
  string status = RecursiveMethod();
  return status;
}

 public string RecursiveMethod()
 {
   string response = "fail";
   if (response =="fail")
   {
     RecursiveMethod();
   }
   return response;
 }
```

The above code working correctly if the response is fail. After the three consecutive fail i changed the response value fail to success. In this the RecursiveMethod function execute three times and it will exit from the loop with fail response. what is the problem in it. In my case if the response is success it will exit from the control. can any one try to help me.

Comment: If you post _fictional_ code then try to post something that actually makes sense and complete enough to reproduce the problem. What you wrote and your code are two separate things.

Comment: i can't see where do you change your `response = "fail"` to `response = "success"` in your code, is this a simplified version or is it your actual code?

Comment: In your example you don't collect the return value of your `RecursiveMethod`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is not clear from your code where the response actually comes from. I'd refactor this to:

```
public string RecursiveMethod()
{
    string response = "fail";

    if (someOtherConditionApplies)
        response = "success";

    if (response == "fail")
    {
        response = RecursiveMethod();
    }

    return response;
}
```

You somewhere have to make sure that you

1. exit the recursion
2. use the result of the recursive call

The question to me, however, is: Why do you use recursion in this case at all?

Answer (score 1):

Add a parameter to the method that is a Int (or a smaller datatype like a short or byte) with the default as 3 and every time it calls itself it should call with the value minus one.

```
public string success() 
{
    string status = RecursiveMethod();
    return status;
}

public string RecursiveMethod(int count = 3)
{
    string response = "fail";
    if (response =="fail" && count > 0)
    {
        RecursiveMethod(--count);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as below and write logic in CheckStatus which will return `fail` or `success`

```
public string success() 
{
  string status = RecursiveMethod();
  return status;
}

 public string RecursiveMethod()
 {
   string response = CheckStatus();
   if (response =="fail")
   {
     RecursiveMethod();
   }
   return response;
 }

string CheckStatus()
{
    //Write Logic on which return "success" or "fail"
}
```